# How to Display Recos in Report Viewer

Tags: vb.net

I`m having a problem in a report that i created it didnt display any records when i run the form. It only displays that column name. I`m using microsoft report viewer.

thnks you for your help ^.^

Comment: what did you try? care to show some code.

Comment: 'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'LMSDataSet.tblBookList' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.tblBookListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LMSDataSet.tblBookList)

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

Comment: sir what do you think?

Comment: you need to set report datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss some Code you didn't assign and datasource to your report , Try add this line to your code :

```
Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = Me.LMSDataSet.tblBookList
Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.BindingSource1)
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\yourreport.rdlc"
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: there`s an error its says: DataSources is not a member of 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer'.

Comment: are you use wizerd to generate dataset

Comment: yes sir i`m using wizard

Comment: i update my code check please

Comment: sir thnks for lots of your answers